# Ошибка в PDO Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Вообщем работаю с PDO недавно и уже говолу сломал понять немогу в чем ошибка вот код:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("(SELECT COUNT(goods_id) as count_rows FROM goods WHERE goods_brandid = :category AND visible='1')
           UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(goods_id) as count_rows FROM goods WHERE goods_brandid IN 
          (SELECT brand_id FROM brands WHERE parent_id = :category) AND visible='1')");
$stmt->execute(array("category" => $category));

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if($row['count_rows']) $count_rows = $row['count_rows'];
}
return $count_rows;
```

А вот какая вылазит ошибка:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number in D:\OpenServer\domains\InterMag.ru\model\model.php:138 Stack trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\InterMag.ru\model\model.php(138): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\InterMag.ru\controller\controller.php(140): count_rows(Object(PDO), 5) #2 D:\OpenServer\domains\InterMag.ru\index.php(10): require_once('D:\\OpenServer\\d...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\InterMag.ru\model\model.php on line 138
```

Подскажите где ошибка??

Comment: Повторное использование псевдопеременных допускается только в режиме эмуляции. У Вас дважды использована псевдопеременная `:category`. См. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы пофиксить эту ошибку в данном конкретном случае, есть два пути:

1. Включить [режим эмуляции](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation_on)
2. Передать переменную в запрос дважды, то есть сделать что-то вроде

   ```
   $stmt->execute(array("category1" => $category,"category2" => $category));
   ```

   соответствующим образом поменяв плейсхолдеы в запросе.

Впрочем, нет ни малейшего смысла выполнять эти два запрос через юнион, и проще всего будет выполнить их по отдельности.

Comment: Двоеточия когда отменили?

Comment: их никогда и не вменяли

Comment: И мануалы врут? http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: ну вообщем понятно похоже в PDO нельзя использовать один плейсхолдер дважды в одном запросе

Comment: @Moonwolf45 вообще-то можно, о чем и написано в моем ответе.

Answer (score -1):

Поправьте ключ в массиве, который вы передаёте в execute();

```
$stmt->execute(array(":category" => $category));
```